# A command-line or batch cmd to concatenate multiple files

Tags: windows, command-line

I have 50 text files in one directory.

Is there a Windows command-line method to concatenate those files into a single file?

I am using [Windows Vista](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Vista).

I don't want to type the name of all files.

Comment: which version of DOS are you using? :) c'mon, give us some more info, what file types ... you're obviously looking for a way to merge those files.

Comment: The post is edited

Comment: DOS in Windows NT-based OS's (NT, 2000, and everything since XP) really isn't DOS, it's a command shell called "cmd.exe".  removed DOS tags to reflect this.

Comment: sorry for that , i really didn't knew that. I was thinking as DOS

Comment: thankfully, the last vestiges of DOS died with Windows ME.  :)  but no worries -- most everyone still calls the Windows command-line "DOS", so it's not *wrong*, just *inaccurate*.  since real DOS is still used sometimes, i'm cleaning up the DOS tag to be just real DOS questions.

Comment: @~quack: For Windows batch questions it *is* wrong, as the answer is in many cases quite different (due to the actual DOS command line environment being quite inferior).

Answer (score 155):

> I don't want to type the name of all
>   files.

That's easy to be avoided. Open a command prompt in this folder and type the following command:

```
copy /b *.txt newfile.txt
```

Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Now you will have all text files in this folder ordered by date ascending merged into a single file called newfile.txt.

> My ultimate aim is to store the
>   contents of each text file in a separate
>   column of an Excel sheet.

Here's a tutorial that may help you to achieve your "ultimate aim":

**[Merge all CSV or TXT files in a folder in one worksheet](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win021.htm)**

Comment: Is it possible to insert new line character after everyfile

Comment: not with this method.

Comment: whats the other options. my ultimate aim is to store the contents of each text file in separate column of excel sheet. ANy ideas

Comment: @Mirage - updated my answer according to your comment.

Comment: But the problem is how can i add the endline character to each text file. Currently some of files text are in same paragrah in the merged file , so excel put it in one column. OR if i can append some endline character to all the files first and then perform merge operation

Comment: Link moved to here: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win021.htm

Comment: For what it is worth -> `copy *.txt merged.txt` is a lot less painful (Windows 7).

Comment: I wonder: Is there any defined order when using such a command? Imagine the files are part of an ISO, so the order may be important.

Answer (score 49):

To add a newLine at the end of each concatenated file, use `type` instead of `copy`, as follows:

```
type *.txt > newfile.txt
```

Comment: WARNING: When you use **type *.txt > newfile.txt**, the text is duplicated.

Comment: Remove `.txt` from `newfile` and bam! There you have it.

Comment: This is an awesome answer for concatenating log files or other things you will parse down the road. Specifically the fact you can do `type x.log.* > merged.log` without a batch file. New lines are pretty easy to deal with.

Comment: Wow, `type` has come a long way since DOS 3.3. I did not know you can use file masks. When did that happen?

Answer (score 41):

Assuming you are talking about appending text files,  the `copy` command can be used to append them together:

```
copy file1+file2+file3 targetfile
```

If you have many files, you could loop by appending one file at a time.

For binary files, add in the '`/b`' option:

```
copy /b file1+file2+file3 targetfile
```

This assumes that you know the binary files you are working with can be appended back-to-back; if not, you will get a lump of useless data.

Comment: This is quite useful if you need to concatenate files in a particular order.

Comment: Microsoft docs on `copy` https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/copy

Comment: The OP said he does *not* want to type in all the names.

Answer (score 10):

Run the following command in the command prompt:

```
for %f in (*.txt) do type "%f" >> output.txt
```

Comment: That does not work as expected, all the text is duplicated in `output.txt`

Comment: Hint *.txt matches output.txt

Comment: @DavidPostill, I've edited the answer according to your concern.

Answer (score 3):

The following .bat file will append all *.for files, except the one named XIT.for, to a blank file named MASTER.for

```
type NUL > MASTER.for
FOR %%G IN (*.for) DO IF NOT "%%G" == "XIT.for" copy /A MASTER.for+"%%G" && echo. >> MASTER.for
```

:)

Comment: A slight twist on the above:
if one wants to make sure the files are concatenated _alphabetically_, one should use:
FOR /F %%G IN ('dir /b /o *.for') DO IF NOT "%%G" == "XIT.for" copy /A MASTER.for+"%%G" && echo. >> MASTER.for

Comment: I like this. Another tweak I needed today is for for a filename header to be printed into the file to separate the input files.

    `for %f in (*.txt) do ((echo. & echo == %f == & echo. &  type %f ) >> *.txt.dat )`

Comment: I am aware that using a bash shell would probably make more sense!

Answer (score 0):

```
set n=50
for /l %i in (1,1,%n%) do type file%i.txt >> file.txt
```

Works on both binary & text files & ensures files concatenate consecutively (1-50).
Tested on Win 10 CMD