# How can I combine two files on Windows?

Tags: windows, combine

I have created a split file on a Linux system as indicated in this [Unix.SE question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6724/what-linux-utility-can-split-a-large-file-into-a-multi-file-archive-that-can-be-o/6727#6727). However, when I copy that file to a Windows system, I cannot recreate the original file. Using 7-zip gives me an error about it being unable to detect the file as a splitted file, and using copy first-file + second-file output-file gives me a 50kb output instead of the correct 7GB output.

What is the correct way to combine two files on Windows?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/111825/any-command-line-or-batch-cmd-to-concatenate-multiple-files

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Add the `/b` parameter to indicate it's binary:

```
copy /b example1.ext + example2.ext example.ext
```

Comment: seems to work, though the copy /? documentation seems it might suggest a /B after each file like in bui's answer, but indeed it seems you only need the one /B after copy. As you've done.

Answer (score 2):

I've used [HJSplit](http://www.hjsplit.org/) in the past with remarkable success.  It's pretty straight-forward and simple to use, and it helps avoid typos on the command line (although the command line works just as well)

Answer (score 0):

```
set n=2
for /l %i in (1,1,%n%) do type file%i.ext >> file.out
```

Works on both text & binary files.
Tested on Win 10 CMD.