# Windows - Combine multiple text files into a single text file

Tags: windows, batch-file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any command-line or batch cmd to concatenate multiple files?](https://superuser.com/questions/111825/any-command-line-or-batch-cmd-to-concatenate-multiple-files)

I have over a thousand text files which I would like to combine into a single text file, is there any way to do this automatically?

Comment: Are they all in the same directory? Do you have a list of the all the files?

Comment: They are all in the same directory and I don't have a list of the file names.

Comment: Then JC2k8's answer should do what you need. Don't forget to come back and accept it later if it does.

Comment: more catchy title then the duplicated one, so +1

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Pull out your command line and let's go:

`copy /a *.txt concat.txt`

This will concatenate all txt files in the same directory into one file named "concat.txt".

`/A` indicates an ASCII text file

Comment: short question, short answer +1 (only tiny blemish, the changing case of the /a)

Comment: The `/a` or `/A` option seems to be less useful then expected. I'm getting garbage line feeds in the concatenated file after the first file. Maybe this option is now outdated because many of alternative formats are around: you mostly think it's ASCII, but it isn't `/b` will do, if the last line ends with linefeed.