# Windows command to concatenate multiple files in alphabetical/numerical order?

Tags: windows, command-line, concatenation

I have several hundred files that need to be concatenated into a single file, much like [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/111825/any-command-line-or-batch-cmd-to-concatenate-multiple-files). The problem is, that my files **must** must be in order. They are named with a Julian date followed by the file type.

Here's an example of the naming schema:

```
152_1605.old
155_0935.old
156_1535.old
```

etc.

This is not something I do very often and I could write my own complicated script to do this, but I feel there is a **much** easier way to do it and I just don't know what that way is.

Comment: Are these *text* files?

Comment: Yes, they are pipe delimited text files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a powershell two-liner:

```
$TextFiles = Get-Item C:\Users\sudo\Documents\MachineLists\*.list

$TextFiles | sort | foreach { Add-Content -Value $(Get-Content $_) -Path C:\users\sudo\Desktop\concat.LIST}
```

As you can see from the first line it helps if they're all in the same folder, which I'm sure you won't have a problem with.

Comment: Awesome. It seems to have worked perfectly. I really need to get more familiar with Powershell. Thanks much!