# combine multiple text files, _+ filenames_, into a single text file

Tags: windows, filenames, org-mode

I would like to combine a handful of text files, but with titles (EDIT: filenames). Ideally, something like

```
* a filename 
contents of file
... 
* another filename 
contents of file 
... 

etc...
```

I am in windows (not DOS), but have access to powershell, pandoc, emacs, cygwin, or anything else you recommend. (Clearly I'm a newb trying out org-mode.)

I can easily put them all in one folder. But I would like to avoid typing the name of each file. If a bat file is recommended, I have never used one, but am willing to learn.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://superuser.com/questions/111825/any-command-line-or-batch-cmd-to-concatenate-multiple-files).

Comment: @Rajib, I did not understand that that question wanted the titles interspersed with the combined text.

Comment: Ah now i see you mean filename. Sorry I misunderstood "Title of file".

Comment: ah, I will edit to adhere to nomenclature, but leave the term in question for search terms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am sure there is something more clever, but here is a powershell script will combine all files:

```
$files = (dir *.txt)
$outfile = "out.txt"

$files | %{
    $_.FullName | Add-Content $outfile
    Get-Content $_.FullName | Add-Content $outfile
}
```

Is it efficient? Not terribly... but it will work in a pinch.

Comment: That works tremendously. I simply navigated to the folder, right clicked the frame to paste your script, and hit <RET>. I can do a find replace to switch `C:\txt\` to `**`.

Comment: To clarify my comment for posterity, I navigated from within PowerShell.

Comment: @BradyTrainor, if you only want the filename, but not the path, switch the line which is `$_.FullName | Add-Content $outfile` to read `$_.Name | Add-Content $outfile`.

Comment: Thank you Mitch. So that I might continue to stave off learning the code, how might I add a string such as `" ** "`?

Comment: You can arbitrarily format things using the `-f` operator.  See http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/03/12/use-powershell-to-format-strings-with-composite-formatting.aspx for details.  To make the filename line be `** filename`, you would specify `("** {0}" -f $_.Name) | Add-Content $outfile`

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by the structure of Mitch's script, I've written a version for Unix-based environments, such as GNU/Linux and OS X:

```
find -regex '.*\.\(docx?\|org\|rtf\|te?xt\)$' | while read file
do
    echo "* $file" >> target-file.org
    cat "$file" | pandoc -t org >> target-file.org
done
```

(If you don't want to install `pandoc`, simply remove the pipe and command, `| pandoc -t org`.)

This script will find all files in the current directory and its subdirectories which have file extensions as described (`.docx`, etc).

For example, if the list includes `fileA.text` and `fileB.rtf` in subdirectory `subd/`, `targetfile.org` will receive lines such as:

```
* ./subd/fileA.text
<fileA's contents converted to an org file by pandoc>
* ./subd/fileB.rtf
<fileB's contents converted to an org file by pandoc>
```

I think this will leave `target-file.org` in a pretty good state for improving from within Emacs, without the script being too complicated. (Especially if you include the `pandoc` step.)