# Copy large file from remote desktop to local machine

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, remote-desktop, file-transfer

I'm trying to copy a large file (14 Gb) from a remote desktop running "ubuntu" to a local machine
"Windows 10"

but after it finishes copy, I find that the copied size is only 1.6 Gb !!

I tried the solution of activating drives in local resources within the remote desktop window but still not working, any other solutions?

Answer (score 1):

- Sometimes a "push", i.e. logging in remotely to the Ubuntu machine and using *it's* file-copy works better, and sometimes a "pull", i.e. using the Windows copy method works better.
- You can set up the Ubuntu machine as a [SFTP (or SSH) server](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-setup-sftp-server-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-with-vsftpd) and receive the file on Windows with [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/) or [PuTTY](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/), which is also included in WinSCP. This may require opening ports through firewalls.
- You can [set up FTP service](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-setup-ftp-server-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-with-vsftpd) on the Ubuntu PC and [download from a Windows browser or command line](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/access-ftp-server-windows-command-prompt). Not only might this require additional ports through firewalls, some system administrators consider FTP a risk and might forbid it.
- Finally, try working outside the box.

  - Use a [free file sharing site](https://otechworld.com/best-free-file-sharing-sites/). Google currently has a 15 GB limit (which cuts it close), Mega offers 35 GB for a month's trial (which you'd likely need to cancel, or pay),
  - [Break the file into pieces](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54579/how-to-split-larger-files-into-smaller-parts) in Ubuntu and [concatenate the fragments in Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/111825/a-command-line-or-batch-cmd-to-concatenate-multiple-files).
  - Sneaker net; i.e., have someone onsite put the file on a USB drive or XD card and send it to you. At one place I worked, we regularly received HHD's with 300 GB of data... it was far more reliable than using the internet, at that time.